# Trying to search through multiple text files for a specific string. I then want the program to print out the text file that it found the string in

Tags: python

I am a beginner to Python have been trying to create a simple python menu. One of the options asks the user what user they want to search for. Each user will have a text file dedicated to them, and when the user types and searches for that user, it will search through a list of text files in a directory, and then it will print all of the user's details onto the program. I have managed to get my program to search through the text files to find the right user, but I am unsure of how to print the text file onto my program.

Code:

```
import os
from os import listdir
os.system("")
import glob
import os.path

menu()
option = int(input("\n" + "Enter your option: "))
 
while option !=0:
    if option == 1:
        dir_path = r'D:\My project'
        for file in os.listdir(dir_path):
            cur_path = os.path.join(dir_path, file)
            if os.path.isfile(cur_path):
                with open(cur_path, 'r') as file:
                    username = input("Enter a username: ")
                    if username in file.read():
                        print('user found')
                        #Here is where I want to print the contents of the text file that 
                        #has been found
                        menu()
                        break
                    else:
                        print ("Invalid option")
```

I have tried to make the program print "username", "file" etc, but in doing so this only prevents the program from working, as it will think that anything I enter is an invalid option.

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: post the code that causes the error, and the full error trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving the file contents in a variable:

```py
            if os.path.isfile(cur_path):
                with open(cur_path, 'r') as file:
                    contents = file.read()
                    username = input("Enter a username: ")
                    if username in contents:
```

After the first `file.read()`, the file object's position is at the end and nothing will be read in subsequent calls, unless you go back to the start with `file.seek(0)`.
See [Methods of File Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects.) for more details.

As an aside, [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) might be a better fit than `os.path`.